# how to reposition an element inside a jquery html method?

Tags: jquery

For example, I have the following jquery code below:

```
$("#AddToList").html(<p>Testing Internals</p>);
```

How can I reposition the element inside the `html(<p>Testing Internals</p>)` above using the following property and value of:

```
margin-left = 20px
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a little bit of inline CSS magic! [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yAhjZ/)

```
$('p').html('<p style="padding: 10px;">bar</p>');
```

Comment: thanks djthoms, I thought about that, and in my case, it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
#AddToList p {
margin-left : 20px;
}
```

INLINE

```
html(<p style="margin-left:20px;">Testing Internals</p>);
```